# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/sites/s/example.co.uk/artisan on line 46

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a (Laravel) migration on the shell of my production shared hosting server. In the shell, I run the following:

```
/usr/bin/php artisan migrate:make mydatabase
```

and receive the following error:

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /var/sites/s/example.co.uk/artisan on line 46

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/sites/s/example.co.uk/artisan on line 46
```

The error references line 46

```
$artisan = Illuminate\Console\Application::start($app);
```

it doesn't seem to like the backslashes, but this is part of the original config? I don't understand.

Furthermore, no matter what I try to do with `artisan`

```
/usr/bin/php artisan --version

Warning: Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /var/sites/s/example.co.uk/artisan on line 46

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/sites/s/example.co.uk/artisan on line 46
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your php version `php -v`, if it's less than 5.3 you should update it because namespaces were introduced in PHP 5.3

Comment: You know what you're probably right. I just had a thought - my shared host uses multiple versions of PHP for compatibility reasons. When I get back to work I'll try `/usr/bin/php5.4 artisan migrate:make mydatabase` and let you know how I get on!

Comment: Works with `/usr/bin/php-5.4 artisan migrate:make`